# Error 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable for chi2 test code

Tags: python

I am trying to perform chi-square test to determine whether a feature and the target are independent and then only keep the features with a certain p-value from the Chi-Square test. This is the code i currently have but keep getting the error "'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"

This is the code:

```
y = dtf_train["y"]
X_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
p_value_limit = 0.95
dtf_features = pd.DataFrame()
for cat in np.unique(y):
    chi2, p = feature_selection.chi2(X_train, y==cat)
    dtf_features = dtf_features.append(pd.DataFrame(
                   {"feature":X_names, "score":1-p, "y":cat}))
    dtf_features = dtf_features.sort_values(["y","score"], 
                    ascending=[True,False])
    dtf_features = dtf_features[dtf_features["score"]>p_value_limit]

X_names = dtf_features["feature"].unique().tolist()
```

The Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-1028dac02fc2> in <module>
      4 dtf_features = pd.DataFrame()
      5 for cat in np.unique(y):
----> 6     chi2, p = chi2(X_train, y==cat)
      7     dtf_features = dtf_features.append(pd.DataFrame(
      8                    {"feature":X_names, "score":1-p, "y":cat}))

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback error message?

Comment: Why are you changing ```chi2```?  The first iteration,  what does ```chi2(X_train, y==cat)``` return?

Comment: use array_name[index_number] syntax to access an item from an array

Comment: When you do `from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2`, `chi2` is a function. When you run `chi2, p = chi2(X_train, y==cat)`, `chi2` becomes a Numpy array. So in the next iteration it returns the TypeError.